# Upgrade Sencha ExtJs 2.2.3 to ver 6

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs

I am completely in the dark, I inherited a .Net Web Forms app written in 2017 that uses Ext2JS version 2.2.3 from 2007, this app fails all security scans and the 2.2.3 is no longer allowed. I need someone to help point me to upgrading this to the latest version or at least extJs 6.0, also is there any documentation on what has changed between versions? I know nothing of extJs so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Honestly for having recently migrated from ExtJS **6.2.5** to **6.6.0** I can't imagine the work that a **4 MAJOR VERSION** migration represents....

Depending on the complexity of the application you need to migrate, I advise you to evaluate the cost/impact that a new development directly with the 6.6 framework would have.

Especially if you are a beginner in ExtJS because it is a very powerful framework and requires a relatively good knowledge to do the migrations because you will have to modify almost all the xtypes (objects) used.

If after the impact study you realize that migration is still the best choice, here are some links that can help you.

https://www.sencha.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-your-ext-js-3-4-apps-to-ext-js-6/
(It's only explain for 3.4 to 6.6)

Good luck with that.

Comment: I migrated three times, 4 to 5 to 6 to 6.2. Probably the best choice would be to rewrite the application in 6.6. A migration would probably not give less work than that.